# Is it possible to add borders on a grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image]

This is my  list of exercises i want add a border between them so the customer does not confuse  for which exercise is the equipment.
My code is below.

```
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AllExerciseTypes}" SelectionMode="Single" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TheBackgroundColor}" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:ExerciseType">
                    
                    <Grid   
                            Padding="10"  
                            ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*"  
                            RowDefinitions="Auto, *">

                        <Label  
                                FontSize="Body"
                                Grid.Column="1"  
                                FontAttributes="Bold"  
                                Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label  
                            
                                Grid.Row="1"  
                                Grid.Column="1"  
                                FontAttributes="Italic"
                                Text="{Binding TargetedMuscle}" />
                        <Label
                                Text= "{Binding Equipment}" 
                                FontAttributes="Italic"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.Row="1"/>
                        
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I have tried making a frame in which is the grid but dont know how to

Comment: Just wrap the grid in a frame

Comment: You can get more details about Frame from the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with frame

```html
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:ExerciseType">


            <Frame Padding="0.3" BorderColor="#AC94C9">
                <Grid   
                    BackgroundColor="#000000"
                    Padding="15"  
                    ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*"  
                    RowDefinitions="Auto, *">


                     <Label  
                        FontSize="Body"
                        Grid.Column="1"  
                        FontAttributes="Bold"  
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                     <Label  
                    
                        Grid.Row="1"  
                        Grid.Column="1"  
                        FontAttributes="Italic"
                        Text="{Binding TargetedMuscle}" />
                    <Label
                        Text= "{Binding Equipment}" 
                        FontAttributes="Italic"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Grid.Row="1"/>
                
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Border to do this you can also configure your border

```
<Border Stroke="#C49B33"
    StrokeThickness="4"
    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40,0,0,40"
    Background="#2B0B98"> 
    <Grid/>
</Border
```

Detailed info about Border can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-8.0

Also if you don't want unexpected behavior don't use Frame.